# How to write a patch to Excel VBA codes?

Tags: excel, vba, patch

I've written an algorithm in Excel VBA to process Excel data. After I handed the Excel file to the client, I found some bugs in the codes. How can I write a fix/patch then hand the patch to the client for easy install? Assume that the client has no knowledge of coding in VBA and cannot even open VBA editor.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is: You don't. That's what you get for putting user data and code in the same file. MS Access developers solve this by creating a "front-end" and a "back-end" database, but I don't think this option is available for Excel development.

Comment: Use an AddIn, then send the latest addin version, but standard xlsm not really perhaps another xlsm which opens this and uses VBA Extensibility, but a nightmare :)

Answer (score 0):

Way1:You can import his sheets from old file to new, then kill old file.
Way2:Replace code in old file from new file.