# How to properly write Excel macros for other people

Tags: excel

I recently started writing VBA macros, even though I never learned VBA. So basically I am translating my python knowledge to VBA, which works most of the time.
However I want to improve my coding skills, especially when it comes to working with other people.

Usually I am writing a Macro and then install it on the computer of my colleagues, so that they can use it as well. But the way we develope the macro is currently a try-and-error approach, so I have to edit the code quite often. Currently I just copy paste the new lines into an Email and the person has to exchange that line by themselves.

**My Question:** How do professionals handle updating VBA Macros? Is there something like "patches"? Or can you have a shared "Personal.xlsb", so that all changes are automatically updated for everyone else as well? I am the only person editing the code anyway, the others just use it.

I googled a lot and also looked through stackoverflow, but only found this: [How to write a patch to Excel VBA codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655390/how-to-write-a-patch-to-excel-vba-codes)  where the answer basically was, that you can't write patches. But there surely must be a way, to update my macros in a better way, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We had a macro that was used by people in 6 countries, so apart from dealing with all the locale issues, we had to control it. The first call in the macro was to check its ID number with that on our server, if the macro ID was older then it would run a download of the new macro and then run as normal.

Comment: This sounds like I could use it too! Could you maybe provide more info on how to do that? I guess I could figure out how to download the new macro from github f.e., but I don't understand how I automatically include the updated macro and drop the old version.

Comment: You can save it as an add-in (XLAM). Check [How to Create and Use an Excel Add-in](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-add-in/)

Comment: Great thanks! So I create and update the add-in file, and this is what would need to be downloaded? Lets say I put the add-in XLAM on a git repository, then in the add-in it needs a line, that compares the version that is currently running with the one on github, if new version is available, download it. Will that not cause an issue, as the add-in is currently running? Can it update while running?

Comment: If the add-in-file is in read-only-mode you can overwrite it. Excel has to be restarted to run the new version.